# How does Agricola Solo version determine the food at the beginning of each game?

Tags: agricola

At the beginning of each game I start with different amount of food. I understand that it is related to how I end the previous game. What is the rule?

Answer (score 4):

This is in the rules [here](https://lookout-spiele.de/wp-content/uploads/Agricola_EN_old_web.pdf)

On page 9

> To play a Solo game, start with 0 Food.

and later on the same page

> Because you have more permanent Occupations after each
>   game, the goal score that you must reach goes up in each game:
>   In the first game, your goal is 50 points, then 55, 59, 62, 64, 65,
>   66 and 67 points. After the eighth game, the Solo game series is
>   over. (You can of course play on with all permanent Occupation
>   cards, in which case the goal score increases by 1 point per
>   game.) At the start of each game in the series, you receive 1 food
>   for every 2 points by which you exceeded the goal score for the
>   previous game (rounded down).